# rlang::expr(`=`(!!rlang::ensym(x), !!rlang::as_name(y))) causes weird note in devtools::check()

Tags: r, package, devtools, tidyeval

I use the following code in a function that is part of an R package I am writing:

```
x = "a"
y = "b"

rlang::expr(`=`(!!rlang::ensym(x), !!rlang::as_name(y)))
```

It automatically creates arguments for a function further down the line that look like this:

```
a = "b"
```

Which can then be plugged into a function like this:

```
foo(a = "b")
```

The problem is that when I run the `devtools::check()` function I get a note due to this part of the code.

```
my_function : <anonymous>: no visible global function definition for '!<-'
```

I assume the problem is the bang-bang (!!) together with the `=` function but I could not really figure out how to solve this.

Would be great if someone has an idea of what to do to prevent this note from occurring! Thanks a lot!

Edit: Based on MrFlick answer I am now using the following:

```
x = c("a", "b")
y = c("y", "z")

args <- purrr::map2(.x = x,
            .y = y,
            .f = function(x, y){
            rlang::exprs(!!rlang::as_name(x) := !!y)
            })

rlang::expr(foo(!!!unlist(args)))
```

Comment: Have you put `!!` from `rlang` into your NAMESPACE? I typically add `@importFrom rlang !!` on a `NULL` function so I don't have to repeatedly call `rlang::` with it.

Comment: Yes I have `@importFrom rlang as_name ensym expr !!` defined in my namespace but I still get the note. I usually refer to every function with `::` to make clear from what package it is. But yes, `@importFrom` would be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CRAN checks don't really like non-standard evaluation so when it sees you calling the `=` function which it interprets as the `<-` function, it doesn't like it.

The `rlang` package gets around this by defining the `:=` operator when you are trying to dynamically build named parameters. So instead you can build your arguments with

```
args <- rlang::exprs(!!rlang::as_name(x) := !!y)
```

And then inject them into the call with

```
rlang::expr(foo(!!!args))
# foo(a = "b")
```

That should prevent CRAN from trying to find the special assignment operator and is generally how one should use rlang for such a purpose.

Comment: This is the correct answer if the goal is to unquote in an argument list. It is occasionally useful to create functions programmatically with quasiquotation and unquote on the LHS of assignment. In this case, the NOTE can be solved with `globalVariables()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. Use `utils::globalVariables("!<-")` to silence this NOTE.